# elasticsearch still creating mappings ad-hoc with dynamic mapping disabled

Tags: java, elasticsearch, dynamic-mapping

I don't seem to understand how to prevent elasticsearch from automatically adding new mappings for new fields. The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/dynamic-mapping.html) states

> Automatic type creation can also be disabled for all indices by setting an index template:

```
PUT _template/template_all
{
  "template": "*",
  "order":0,
  "settings": {
    "index.mapper.dynamic": false 
  }
}
```

So this is what I am doing:

```
client.admin().indices()
    .preparePutTemplate("template_disable_dynamic_mapping")
    .setTemplate("*")
    .setSettings(Settings.builder().put("index.mapper.dynamic", false))
    .get();
```

and after creating an index with a custom mapping for `data`, I can see these mappings and setting, `GET /data/_settings` returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "mappings": {
      "some_type": {
        "properties": {
          "value": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          [...]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "mapper": {
        "dynamic": "false"
      },
      [...]
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I index a document with a new field `foo`, it gets inserted successfully and my new mapping looks like this: `GET /data/_mapping`

```
{
  "data": {
    "mappings": {
      "some_type": {
        "properties": {
          "foo": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          [...]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My expectation was that no new mapping would be created.

Comment: Are you sure the template was saved properly (the way you expected it to be)? Check the list of templates with `GET /_template`.

Comment: @Andrei Stefan The template exists exactly as expected. @halileohalilei thanks, following that question I was able to solve it by setting the mapping's `dynamic` to `strict`